# Windows 10 not recognized anymore on boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, safe-mode

I have a Windows 10 laptop that one day stopped booting (my wife was using it, she doesn't know what caused it).

If I boot it normally, it shows the blue windows and the rotating dots for a while, then goes to black screen, no cursor, no mouse. the only thing that I can do at this step is to turn it off.

I tried F8 and Shift + F8 to go to safe mode, but those keys do not work, even if I am not using uefi.

If I place a USB stick with Win 10 image on it (downloaded iso with windows tool and put on stick with rufus) the OS loads fine and I get to desktop.

I tried everything with bootrec (fixmbr, fixboot, scanos, rebuildbcd) but the only os that is found has path on windows.old, and I think that is the old Win 7 (before updating to win 10).

Why Win 10 on c:\windows folder is not recognized? How do I fix this?

Comment: how it finished?:) I have the same issue now:)

Comment: @P.K. I had to format and reinstall Windows 10. I didn't had that issue anymore. I didn't find any other way unfortunately.